# Passing of request object

Tags: java, httprequest

Does request exists if it is called in this fashion

```
public class A
 {
   public void methodA(HttpServletRequest request)
     {
         B.getValues(request);//gets the value

     }

    public static void getA(HttpServletRequest request)
      {
           String x=request.getParameter("X");
      }
}

  public class B
  {
     public static void getValues(HttpServletRequest request)
      {
          A.getA(request);
      }
  }
```

Now request is passed from methodA to a method of Class B. where the method in Class B is calling a function in Class A to get the value. Does the request object still holds the values(request still exists) if the request is passed in this circular fashion. Is this a good programming methodology.

Comment: for your program HttpServletRequest (request) is just like another object why you think that you will loose ?.

Comment: No, passing an object from `A` to `B` back to `A` without a *really* good reason is not good methodology. If you have such a reason, please explain.

Comment: instead of passing request why don't you pass the value after getting it from request. i.e.get this request.getParameter("X") and pass.

Comment: Your HttpServletRequest(request) doesn't have any difference with other objects,why do you think it will lose value ?I don't think such a  loop call is necessary.When request is passed to a function as a paramter, which is actually passed in is just a reference to this object.That is to say,no matter we call B.getValues(),A.getA() and so on , their parameters is references pointing to the same object,namely the same memory data.